# What is this ornamental plant with leaves similar to corn?

Tags: identification, ornamental-plant

I saw this plant in a park in Silistra (Bulgaria) and I don't know what it is. There were people nearby but I don't speak their language, so I couldn't ask. I tried to take a more detailed picture of the flowers, but they were all starting to wilt and not looking well on close-ups.

My mother says her parents had a plant similar to this one. The roots were taken out from soil during winter and stored inside, otherwise they wouldn't have survived the local temperature of -15 degrees Celsius (5 degrees Fahrenheit).

The pictures were taken in late September (beginning of autumn).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The leaves make me think it is a Canna Lily or "Canna indica". Strictly speaking, they aren't lilies exactly, but are loosely related to ginger.

Comment: Yep, that is a Canna Lily...they are still toxic to animals...

Comment: A favorite of municipal park systems who can grow the tubers in early spring and then plant out where it will flower most of the summer.  Somewhat tender in regards to low temperatures